# Dual boot 14.04 and windows 7 but windows not booting

Tags: dual-boot

I installed 14.04 along side windows 7. Previously had option to select windows 7 or 12.04.

Now system goes direct to 14.04, no option for windows7.

windows shows up in the file system, seems to be fine, just can't get to windows 7 if I need to.boot

Answer (score 1):

You may just need to update GRUB (the boot window that gives you the option to select between Ubuntu and Windows.

Open the terminal and type the following command

`sudo update-grub`

this may fix your problem.

Comment: or alternatively "sudo grub-install /dev/sda"